# Visual Studio 2015 strange Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: c#, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015

I just went over to `VS 2015` from 2013. Back in 2013 I was using `Alt + Shift + (` for typing the `{` character. In `VS 2015` the same command toggles the error display for the scroll bar and wont let me type the opening curly bracket.

I've tried to track down this awful shortcut in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` but without any success.

Anyone know how to remove this or override it with my desired shortcut?

Edit: 
I'm using Resharper 9.2 Ultimate and it's keyboard scheme : **ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA** over Visual Studios default scheme. I've tried with both schemes and none of them seems to solve this issue. So this should not be the cause of the problem, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Regarding the keyboard layout: I'm using a Swedish one (sv) and it looks like this: [image]

And my physical keyboard looks like this (Mac): [image]

**Note** 
I'm using the following vs setup :

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
>
> Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework
>
> Version 4.6.00081
>
> Installed Version: Professional

To clarify even more:

[image]
[image]

Notice the green little checkbox, that indicates if there are any errors or warnings, on picture two. This is what's getting toggled while using the desired command inside VS.

Comment: Either this is a typo or there's wrong with your keyboard and/or your previous shortcuts. This has *nothing* to do with Visual Studio. Are you using a non-QWERTY (or non-US QWERTY) keyboard layout perhaps? The typical location of `{` is above `[`. Pressing `Shift + [` should return `{`. In fact, you need to type `Shift + 9` to get `(` so your keystroke can't be `Alt + Shift + (` in a common layout

Comment: For those that are interested I'm guessing the OP's keyboard looks something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/KB_Sweden.svg/2000px-KB_Sweden.svg.png)

Comment: @ntohl There is no such mapping in VS, new or old. This is a Windows issue - some layouts use the *right* Alt as a shortcut to typing special "Graphics" characters. The common QWERTY layout doesn't need that. Keyboard-level shortcuts take precedence over application shortcuts

Comment: The big thing we're missing to make this a reproducible issue is knowing what your keyboard settings for Windows are (what keyboard layout are you using? en-US? en-UK? something else?) and what/if any changes you've made to Visual Studio's default keymapping.  Keep in mind, this question *is* on topic, but even if it's on topic, we have to be able to know definitively what the OP is using so that we can definitively answer (and so that future users with the same issue can determine if they have the same keyboard layout with certainty).

Comment: Guys, why are you asking him for his keyboard layout? He's only asking how to find (and change the shortcut to toggle the error display. This has nothing to do with the keyboard, it is a VS setting.

Comment: Carl, is your VS 2015 the standard English edition? If not, please specify. Also specify the type of edition you have (e.g. community, professional, etc).

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081

Installed Version: Professional

Comment: What do Alt-7 and Alt-0 do? https://mooselander.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/brackets-on-a-swedish-keyboard/

Comment: Now here's the deal, the command: Alt-Shift-8 works fine outside of the VS environment. But as soon as I'm trying to use it within VS it toggles the scrollbar instead. Typing ending brackets with Alt-Shift-9 works fine inside VS. It seems to be some strange "default-command" within VS that causes this problem.

Comment: What you can do is trying to find under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard the command which interferes with yours and reassign it to other keys. Also maybe this list may help although Alt-Shift-8 seems to be not included: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

Comment: And maybe this article I found right now might also help: http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/10/10/using-mac-navigation-keys-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ReSharper keybinding. The default keybinding is `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 8`. It sounds like you are either holding more keys than you intend or have ended up giving it a keybinding that conflicts with your keyboard setup.

To change the keybinding go to `Tools > Options > Keyboard` again and search for `ReSharper_EnableDaemon`. You can remove the keybinding or set it to something else.

Comment: Thanks :), now it works like a charm. Still toggles the scrollbar analysis though